# Why web crawler must have these properties like robustness, politeness etc

Tags: web, search, web-crawler

Why web crawler must have robustness, politeness, scalablity, quality, freshness and extensibility ?

Answer (score 0):

**Robustness**: a web crawler must be robust to changes in web site contents. Web search needs to retrieve and index every new web page as soon as possible. if a website just became online, the crawler needs time to go through all the front nodes at the queue in frontier before focusing on this new website. To tackle this web crawler has distributed system which index different web pages with different specification

**Politeness**: a web search must respect every web server's policies to re-index their web pages. if a web crawler is asked not to crawl a page aggressively by a certain web server, the crawler can put that page into a priority queue and re-index it when the queue is at top

**Scalability**: new webpages are added every day on the internet, web crawler must index every page asap. for this it needs fault tolerance, distributed systems, extra machines, etc. if a certain node at a web crawler has a fault, other nodes can divide its work and index the particular web pages.

**Quality**: web search ability to get useful web pages to every user. if the page contains entries which contain content far from user's recent searches or user's interests, the web search must use the previous user experience to predict what kind of content user might like

**Freshness**: web crawler's ability to fetch and index fresh copies of each page. for eg news websites are updated every second and needed to be re-index urgently. for this web crawler keep a separate priority queue for such priority based contents, to reindex such pages in a small period of time.

**Extensibility**: during early times, new data formats, languages, and new protocols were introduced. web-crawlers ability to cope with new and unseen data formats and new protocols is called extensibility, this suggests that web crawler architecture must be modular so that changes in one module would not affect others. if a website would contain a new data format unknown to web crawler then the web crawler can fetch the data but requires human intervention to add the data format details to the crawler index module.